# The if condition in my Python code is always false

Tags: python

I'm trying the code below:

```
Erick = input ("Kobia, what's ur favourite team ?")
print (" ")

if Erick.upper() == "manchester city":

    print ('All hail Pep.')
    print ('Heri nyinyi kuliko Man united,')
    print ('Liverpool have been awful this season.')
 
else: 
    print ('Arsenal gladly sit on top of the table.')

print (" ")
```

When I input the string `'manchester city'`, the code only prints out the '`else`' part of the function

Whatever I type in, the code prints out the '`else`' part of the function

What might the problem be ?

Comment: You have `if Erick.upper() == "manchester city":`. There is not even one upper character in "manchester city".

Answer (score 0):

Try this code where I have only add `.upper()` to the string `'manchester city'`:

```
Erick = input("Kobia, what's ur favourite team ?")
print(" ")

if Erick.upper() == "manchester city".upper():

    print('All hail Pep.')
    print('Heri nyinyi kuliko Man united,')
    print('Liverpool have been awful this season.')

else:
    print('Arsenal gladly sit on top of the table.')

print(" ")
```

You can input `'manchester city'`, `'Manchester City'`, and so on and all inputs are OK for the `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Change condition `Erick.upper() == "manchester city"` to `Erick.lower() == "manchester city"`

Because with your code you are comparing `MANCHESTER CITY` with `manchester city`